# Remove the first part of string

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I have an array which includes some string as (here as an example includes three):

```
@array = ("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
```

I have another array which includes thousand elements in the following form,

```
@senocndArray = (test/Foo/the_Rest_of_string, test/Bar/the_Rest_of_string, test/Baz/the_Rest_of_string)
```

Now what I want to do is to remove the part `test/$element` in the following for loop

```
for my $element(@array){
    my $string = "test/$element";
    for $secondElement(@senocndArray){
        # delete the $string part of each element of @senocndArray
    }
}
```

In the second loop I want to remove the first part and save it in another array or overwrite the `$secondElement`. I tried like

```
$secondElement =~ s/$string //;
```

But it does not work for me. Does anybody could help me please to know where is my mistake?

Comment: Try with `use warnings; use diagnostics;` to get some hints.

Comment: @Сухой27 I have, I have written the main part which shows my question.

Comment: https://eval.in/1029566

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$secondElement =~ s/$string //;
#                          ↑
```

there is a extra space behind the "$string"

Comment: What do you mean by an extra space? I don't see any!

Comment: Royeh, I have edited the answer to include an up arrow `↑` to mark the position of the space in the code. Does this help?

Comment: @daxim Oh, yeah that was really great hint! ;)